# Should I create a new instance of IServiceHubContext each time (with CreateHubContextAsync) or remember and reuse?

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I connection to `Azure SignalR Service` using Managmenet API. I use C# library for that and run this code:

```
var context = await _serviceManager.CreateHubContextAsync(hub);
```

What I failed to figure out is what is the cost of this operation and if there is some pooling behind the scenes. I.e.: should I remember and reuse the context (and it's resilient against errors) or should I create a new hub context for each operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1578:

> You could dispose ServiceManager once you have created the HubContext. And the HubContext is safe to use as a singleton across multiple threads.

Having a look at the code, it looks like the `ServiceManager` creates its own `IHost` to maintain the lifetime of the objects